# Groovy can't see imported Java class in spec: "unable to resolve class ..."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I've run into problem with running test-compile goal using Maven when setting up Spock for my Spring Boot project.
I have Java class named *WcyUrlsFactory* with method *createGroupPageUrl()* that I want to test with Groovy/Spock. Class is located in src/main/java/...

```js
    package pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.session.utils;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher.GroupRequestParams;

import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;

import static pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.session.utils.WcyUrlParams.*;

@Slf4j
public class WcyUrlsFactory {
    private WcyUrlsFactory() {
    }

    public static String createGroupPageUrl(GroupRequestParams params) {
        return createIndexPageUrl(params.getSessionId()) +
                MID.value() +
                iid(params.getSemester(), params.getClock()) +
                exv(params.getGroupName());
    }
...
}
```

Tested method has one argument which is instance of *GroupRequestParams.class*. This class is also located in src/main/java but in different package:

```html
package pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Value;
import pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.session.utils.Semester;

import java.time.Clock;

@Value
@Builder
public class GroupRequestParams {
    private final Clock clock;
    private final String sessionId;
    private final Semester semester;
    private final String groupName;
}
```

I've created spec class in Groovy - class is located in the same package as test subject, in src/test/groovy/... directory:

```js
package pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.session.utils

import pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher.GroupRequestParams
import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.Clock
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.ZoneId

class WcyUrlsFactorySpec extends Specification {
    def "should create group page url for current date"() {
        System.println("It works!")
        expect:
        def clock = clockSetTo(currentTime)
        result == WcyUrlsFactory.createGroupPageUrl(GroupRequestParams.builder()
                .semester(semester)
                .groupName("I8B2S4")
                .sessionId("4a899a8ebf2e7707db28b11419831b6b&t=6799928")
                .clock(clock)
                .build())

        where:
        semester        | currentTime               || result
    ...
    }
}
```

Running test in Idea works fine but when I try to build an artifact with Maven, I get error :

```js
> mvn clean test-compile -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bali-sync 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ bali-sync ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compileTests (default) @ bali-sync ---
[INFO] Using Groovy 2.4.4 to perform compileTests.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.108 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-07T20:41:36+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compileTests (default) on project bali-sync: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: startup failed:
[ERROR] /home/mnowicki/IdeaProjects/bali/bali-sync/src/test/groovy/pl/edu/wat/wcy/bali/sync/service/session/utils/WcyUrlsFactorySpec.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher.GroupRequestParams
[ERROR]  @ line 3, column 1.
[ERROR]    import pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher.GroupRequestParams
[ERROR]    ^
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6:compileTests (default) on project bali-sync: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.CompileTestsMojo.execute (CompileTestsMojo.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:275)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.AbstractCompileMojo.doCompile (AbstractCompileMojo.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.CompileTestsMojo.execute (CompileTestsMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/mnowicki/IdeaProjects/bali/bali-sync/src/test/groovy/pl/edu/wat/wcy/bali/sync/service/session/utils/WcyUrlsFactorySpec.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher.GroupRequestParams
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import pl.edu.wat.wcy.bali.sync.service.fetcher.GroupRequestParams
   ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors (ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits (CompilationUnit.java:946)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation (CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile (CompilationUnit.java:542)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile (CompilationUnit.java:525)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod (ReflectionUtils.java:275)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.AbstractCompileMojo.doCompile (AbstractCompileMojo.java:197)
    at org.codehaus.gmavenplus.mojo.CompileTestsMojo.execute (CompileTestsMojo.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My *pom.xml* has gmavenplus included:

```html
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I move GroupRequestParams.class to the same class as test subject, Maven test passes - how can I make gmavenplus scan sources in src/main/java?

Comment: You'll need to include your full POM. It looks like Maven isn't running `compile` between `clean` and `test-compile` for some reason.

Comment: @chrylis Thank you for answer - in fact you were right, my project was not compiled because of <packaging>pom</packaging> set in pom - removing it solved my problem :)